# Probability using Permutation and Combination for selecting n variables which varies and has a range of r.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

### While learning Statistics and Probability, I was learning difference between theoretical probability and Experimental probability, and all of a sudden a question stumbled upon my mind which is described below:

Let’s say a Cereal company has introduced a gift in the pack and there are 6 different types of gifts. Now in case if I am purchasing 7 packs then what is the probability that I can collect all of the gifts.

Firstly, I am not sure whether the probability shall be calculated with permutation or combination. I tried to solve it for few hours and tried different scenarios but as I am learning the subject I need help on which scenario is appropriate here and which shall be used when?

**Scenario1:** Calculating total count of different permutations we can get by buying 7 packs of cereals:
A pack can contain any of 6 gifts since I am buying 7 packs I have 6 x 6 x 6 x 6 x 6 x 6 x 6 = 6^7 different options of gifts.

**Scenario2:** Calculating what are the scenarios when I am able to get all types of gifts:
I think it shall be equal to 6x5x4x3x2x1 and for 7th I can get any of 6 gift it won’t matter also the order of 1-6 pack and 7th pack can interchange so multiplied that with 2!. So, final answer becomes (6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 x 6) x 2!.

**Scenario3:** Finding total combinations I get buy buying 7 packs of cereals:
In this I didn’t knew how to solve so I tried to find online and I learnt something called **combination with repetition** and there I found some formula as ((n+r-1)/r) where r is number of packs selecting and n is number of different gifts, which is 7 and 6 respectively. So total combinations are 12C7.Again, I didn’t had a clue about this just read about it over the internet.

**Scenario4:** Total combinations when I get all gifts within my 7 purchase
I think it can be answered like (6C1 x 5C1 x 4C1 x 3C1 x 2C1 x 1C1)/6!  x 6C1. I am doing 6C1 x 5C1 x … x 1C1 because I want all gifts selected then dividing it with 6! Because order doesn’t matter. And then multiplying it with 6C1 because in 7th box anything can come out.

TBH, in scenario4 I am having very little confidence on my approach. And further to make my concept clear I have attempted one more example in hope to get guidance over it here:

What if I had purchased 8 box?
In that case I thought that scenario 4 would be calculated as (6C1 x 5C1 x … x 1C1) x (7C2) the reason I gave 7C2 is based on concept of combination with repetition.
In my intuition in order to find the probability we shall find Scenario2/Scenario1.

Now Can you please comment on my approach of all scenarios and calculation of probability.
Also, which scenario shall be used over other in general, from context of probability?

If any of the approach in my scenario is wrong could please suggest on how to think over it?

Answer (score 1):

"Scenario1" is correct.  This is a good choice of a sample space to use.  It is equiprobable, which we like, and it is easy to organize our thoughts with.  Note that this choice of sample space makes it so that order matters.  We must then be consistent with our choices on how to enumerate the events.  Note also that if we decided that order did not matter for our sample space this makes it so that the outcomes we are counting are not equally likely to occur which is not at all helpful.

---

"Scenario2" is wrong.  That is two times the number of ways in which very specifically the first six boxes opened had all six prizes.  It could have been the case that you got a repeat within the first six boxes and the seventh box was a new unique prize.  Multiplying by two did not fix this problem.

If you insisted on wanting to correct this, pick which two positions both gave the same prize.  From left to right, pick which prize was found in that position (*noting that when picking the prize for the left-most of the pair that share a prize, you effectively also pick the prize for the right part of the pair too and so skip that one later*).  This gives a total of $\binom{7}{2}\cdot 6!$.

This approach however is hardly salvageable for generalizing to the larger problem... if we were to do so we would need to find all possible ways to split this up and perform a calculation for each outcome separately.

---

"Scenario3" is wrong because it does not keep track of ensuring that all outcomes are seen at least once and it does not keep track of which box was which in the process.

This approach is not salvageable for generalizing to the larger problem.

---

"Scenario4" is wrong.  The order in which things occur is important and can not be ignored.  This approach is not salvageable.

---

---

As for a correct approach which is generalizable: we use [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) over the events that at least one particular prize is missing.  We subtract this probability away from $1$ to get the probability that all prizes are present.

This gives us a probability of $1 - \sum\limits_{i=1}^6\binom{6}{i}\left(\frac{(6-i)}{6}\right)^7$ or more generally with $p$ prizes and $b$ boxes purchased $1 - \sum\limits_{i=1}^p\binom{p}{i}\left(\frac{p-i}{p}\right)^b$

Alternatively, we can cheat and use [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) which is notation used for writing the answer to exactly this and related problems.  The answer will simply be:

$$\frac{{b\brace p}p!}{p^b}$$

Comment: As a newbie to PnC meanwhile I understand all this things could please comment on below:
Lets say apart from calcuating the correct way of calculating probability isn't the approach is correct for scenario 3 for what I was trying to find i.e. combinations of selecting 6 gifts in 7 packs? 

And in Scenario 2 If I correct my approach as below:
We have blank spaces as _ and gifts as A to F
_A_B_C_D_E_F_
The 7th gift pack can be located anywhere in this 7 _
and 7th gift can be anything between A to F. So Total permutation becomes 6!*7*6.

Comment: In continuation to my comment Further in approach 4 while validating I used below approach:
possible combinations would be
A B C D E F (A-F) which would result in 6 cases which matches with my approach.
What would you say on that?

Comment: @KishanThacker how do you differentiate between *A_B_C*$\color{red}{C}$*D_E_F* and *A_B*$\color{red}{C}$*C_D_E_F*?  Those both look like ABCCDEF to me.  That is where your overcounting by a factor of two comes in.

Comment: Okay, so I think I am able to get why 6!*6*7 shall be divided by 2. But not able initiate think process on how to come up with that on my own like not getting inuition on why that shall be done, although I do understand that my approach is having few duplicates.
I really would like thank you for your responses, Sir!
What about other scenario that I mentioned in my comment are they making sense?